# Choice of splitting in domain decomposition algorithms

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, soft-question, na.numerical-analysis

When solving a PDE numerically by domain decomposition methods, what is the "optimal way" to split the domain? Are there any results stating that a particular partition of the domain yields "better" convergence than other partitions?

For concreteness, let us consider the classical Poisson equation $-\Delta u = f(x)$ with homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions.

Comment: You may have better luck asking on scicomp.SE.